# Symfony2/Doctrine2 - Issue when getting datetime from database

Tags: php, database, datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm

As I was working on my Symfony2 project a strange bug savagely appeared (again).

I created an entity `Check` containing a `dateCreated` attribute and some others attributes so I can link `Check` to different entities that are extending a `ProductBase`. Here are samples of `Check` and a `AProduct` :

```
/**
 * Check
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="check")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Check
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;
    [...]


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\AProduct", inversedBy="checks")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="aproduct_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $aproduct;
    [...]
}


/**
 * AProduct
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="aproduct")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AProduct extends ProductBase
{
    [...]


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Check", mappedBy="product")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateCreated" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $checks;
    [...]
}
```

So my problem is that when I am trying to display the `dateCreated` attribute in one of my controller, see code below, Symfony2 (or Doctrine2) is adding exactly one month to the date stored in the database and I don't know why it's happening :

```
[...]
$aproduct = $aproducts[0];
$checks = $aproduct->getChecks();
$lastCheck = $checks->toArray()[0]; //I know it's not 'safe' but it's shorter to expose my problem
var_dump($lastCheck->getDateCreated());
```

Result :

```
object(DateTime)[854]
  public 'date' => string '2014-01-20 16:21:41' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

Value stored in database :

```
2013-12-20 16:21:41
```

What I don't understand the most is that in another controller, with the exact same methods but on a different product (`BProduct` for instance), I get the correct date...
Has anyone already faced to this problem or have any clue of what to do to solve it?

Thank you again. If you need more information just ask and I will try to help as most as I can.

Edit : The others `aproduct` stored in `aproducts` are displaying the correct date...

Comment: are you using a custom datetime type as suggested here? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#handling-different-timezones-with-the-datetime-type

Comment: @YRM why would timezone affect a DateTime by an entire month?

Comment: I would print-debug what happens in Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType::convertToPHPValue(), the problem is probably in your own code.

Comment: @sjagr it wouldn't, im just asking if he is using a custom datetime because then we would need to see it..

Comment: @YRM No, I am not using custom datetime here. But I was wondering the same thing as sjagr. Your lecture is interesting thought.

Comment: @OndřejMirtes when doing a print-debug in `convertToPHPValue()` the input and ouput is the good one. It's probably in my code, yes, but I don't understand why only the first object of my array is wrong...

Comment: How about you `var_dump($checks->first())` so you can see if the entire record is correct

Comment: @sjagr yup the entire record is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found my problem and my post here was really silly and completely unrelated to Symfony or Doctrine, sorry about that.
I was performing some "tests" on the last instance of my `aproduct` checks before displaying them and those "tests" were affecting the `dateCreated` value.
Here is what I was doing :

```
public static function updateAProductStatus(AProduct $product){
    if(($check = $product->getChecks()->first()) instanceof Check){
        $date = $check->getDateCreated();
        $expiracyDate = $date->add(new \DateInterval('P1M')); //this line is the problem
        $status = self::getStatus($expiracyDate); //this is only returning 'expired', 'expiring' or 'good' based on the difference between today's date and dateCreated + 1 month
    } else {
        $status = 'expired';
    }
    return $status;
}
```

So, as written in the code, `$date->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));` is changing the stored value of `Checks`'s `dateCreated` attribute. I don't understand exactly why it's affecting it because I'm not working directly on the `Check` instance.

The quick way to solve it was to explicitly clone the `DateTime` instance before adding a `DateInterval` :

```
$date = clone $date;
```

But I will add a new field in my `Check` or `AProduct` entity to store the expiracy date instead of calculating it on every update.

Update:

I read that PHP passes objects and arrays as reference and not as value. That's why I was having a problem here. I didn't know PHP was acting like that. I will be more careful in the future then!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using:

```
@ORM\OrderBy({"dateCreated" = "DESC"})
```

Might be silly but check the id of returned Check instance.

Comment: It's not silly. But the id of `Check` instance is the good one.

Comment: Ok. Is there some important code in ProductBase.php? Did you put `$this->checks = new ArrayCollection()` in __construct?

Comment: This line is present. There is no important code in `ProductBase`, only the basic getters and setters... There is no other code interacting with checks in those entities... Tomorrow I will continue to look everywhere to maybe find where come this issue from. Thank you all for trying to help me